# How can I connect and set bluetooth headphones to PC with Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, headphones

I have:

```
PC with Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Bluetooth dongle: 'easy idea'  (5.0)
Headphones: JBL 125 BT
There isn't anything displayed in the UI Bluetooth settings.
```

I opened the console.

```
myuser@123:~$ sudo bluetoothctl
Agent registered
enter code here

[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
```

How can I connect and set bluetooth headphones to PC?

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list; dmesg | grep -i blue
Subsystem: TP-LINK Technologies Co., Ltd. TG-3468 Gigabit PCI Express Network Adapter [7470:3468]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
3: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
[1.470798] usb 1-2: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[    4.364538] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.364561] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.364563] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.364565] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.364567] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.376363] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: examining hci_ver=0a hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0a lmp_subver=8761
[    4.377359] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[    4.377361] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761a_fw.bin
[    4.381286] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761a_config.bin
[    4.381303] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8761a_config.bin failed with error -2
[    4.381308] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz -2, total sz 20204
[    5.536889] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.536891] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.536893] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.486026] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc20 tx timeout
[   14.646080] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: download fw command failed (-110)
[23064.487359] usb 1-2: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[23066.502394] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout
[23074.534297] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: HCI_OP_READ_LOCAL_VERSION failed (-110)
[31657.162281] usb 1-1: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[31657.164650] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: examining hci_ver=0a hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0a lmp_subver=8761
[31657.165642] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[31657.165645] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761a_fw.bin
[31657.170506] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761a_config.bin
[31657.170550] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8761a_config.bin failed with error -2
[31657.170563] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz -2, total sz 20204
[31659.269331] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc20 tx timeout
[31667.333171] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: download fw command failed (-110)
[31694.285695] usb 1-1: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[31694.288683] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: examining hci_ver=0a hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0a lmp_subver=8761
[31694.289694] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[31694.289698] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761a_fw.bin
[31694.289933] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761a_config.bin
[31694.289954] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8761a_config.bin failed with error -2
[31694.289963] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz -2, total sz 20204
[31696.388847] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc20 tx timeout
[31704.452799] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: download fw command failed (-110)
```

Comment: does [this article](https://net2.com/how-to-set-up-bluetooth-on-ubuntu-18-04/) answer your question?

Comment: Bluetooth Manager popup buttons (Search, Adapter, and Device)  aren't  clickable

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list; dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I add command lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list; dmesg | grep -i blue

Answer (score 0):

As you can see `rtl_bt/rtl8761a_config.bin` is missing.

It is really missing in Ubuntu 18.04 repository. It is a bug that can be reported by `linux-bug linux-firmware`.

You need to find this firmware file and copy it to `/lib/firmware/rtl_bt`

You can download this archive

https://mpow.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/mpow_BH519A_driver+for+Linux.7z

Unpack it and extract `rtl8761a_config` from `rtkbt-firmware/lib/firmware/rtlbt/`. Rename it to `rtl8761a_config.bin` and copy it to `/lib/firmware/rtl_bt` directory.

Then reboot or run

```
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Comment: Oops there is no this file there either.

Comment: sudo cp rtl8761a_config.bin /lib/firmware/rtl_bt

cp: cannot stat 'rtl8761a_config.bin': No such file or directory

Comment: You need to find it somewhere. If it is a dual boot, it should be in Windows.

Comment: I have only Linux

Comment: I did all what you wrote. But What can I do after 'sudo cp rtl8761a_config.bin /lib/firmware/rtl_bt
  
[1]+  Killed                  blueman-manager
' comand? P.S. You delete your previous instruction

Comment: I wrote what to do next.